Is it "on the world's stage" or "on the world stage"?
I'm writing some lyrics and I want them to be correct, when we talk about someone being in the media around the world, especially a politician, are they "on the world's stage" or "on the world stage"?


Lyrics don't have to be "correct"; 2. "On the world's stage" and "on the world stage" are both metaphors and, as such, fall under that gentle rubric of "figurative language," meaning you have a lot of leeway.


There isn't a grammatical and an ungrammatical option, rather an idiomatic and a pretty unidiomatic one. Google ngrams indicate that the attributive rather than the Saxon genitive is almost universally preferred here (as is usual for associative rather than 'true ownership' relationships).

With these phrases, both will sound very similar and be hard to distinguish when spoken/sung because of the sibilants (stage starting /s/). So it probably doesn't matter, as either will do.
